# Outlet Collection with Label

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel

I made an Outlet Collection called `labelCollection`.
Then I created 36 `Lables` in Interface Builder and tagged them 1-12.
So I have at least 3 Labels with the same Tag in that construction.

How can I set the same text to the Labels with identical tags.

```
Say:
label with tag 1 gets letter "A"
label with tag 2 gets letter "B"
...
label with tag 12 gets letter "K".
```

When this is done I would like to fade out the whole `labelCollection` with all labels at once after 2 seconds.

So, how can I control specific labels in the `labelCollection`?
and how can I control the whole `labelCollection` for animation (fade out)?

Thank you very much
Best regards
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
for(UILabel* label in self.view.subview) {

  switch(label.tag) {
  case:0
     label.text = @"A";
  } break;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

And for animation you can try this -

```
   view1.alpha = 1.0;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     label.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];
```

Comment: Retro,I am on my way here with Xcode...Its a bigger concept I have in my mind which helps me to have a practical use to work along...I try to absorb the information as good as I can, reading and trying a lot. And not to forget having kind help from you experienced guys. Cool from your side!!! Thanks a lot!!! @NSS:  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: the only major mistake here is that it will work with ***all*** `UILabel` objects in the view, not just with the outlet collection's.